# Quantifying similarity between datasets with non-linear structures using Hilbert Space

Tags: probability-distributions, hilbert-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

Here's a revised version of your Stack Overflow question with some errors corrected and improved clarity:

---

I have a dataset that represents movements between two locations (origin and destination), and for each location, there are three associated attributes. The dataset structure looks like this:

```
- movements_count
- o_id
- o_geo_attr1
- o_geo_attr2
- o_geo_attr3
- d_id
- d_geo_attr1
- d_geo_attr2
- d_geo_attr3
- geo_distance
- travel_time
```

The dataset exhibits non-linearity, and I'd like to compare two datasets with this structure to quantify the distance or similarity between them. I've come across the concept of Hilbert Space, and I'm wondering if this is a suitable method for achieving this purpose. Additionally, are there any simpler or more appropriate methods for this task?

Comment: Why the heck do people think they have to pull out the infinite-dimensional concept of a Hilbert space, when all they are doing is finite-dimensional? A finite dimensional vector space is all you need - if you even need that much. (To be sure, finite dimensional vector spaces with inner products are Hilbert spaces too, but the raison-d'etre of Hilbert spaces is explore what happens in infinite dimensions.) However, this doesn't address the real question you need to answer, which is how you want to weight differences in your characteristics when combining them.

Comment: For example, when counting fruit, you can have apples, oranges, and grapes. Apples and oranges generally compare fairly easily. But grapes? Should you just go by number? Or maybe you should compare by weight? Or maybe by volume? Or maybe by cost? These are questions we cannot answer for you because we don't know what your are doing, what these characteristics are and what you hope to accomplish by these comparisons. Math will not itself help you here. The math comes in only once you have made those decisions.